# C# Method where constraint T:V

Tags: c#, generics, methods, interface

I have this method:

```cs
void SomeMethod<T,V>() where T:V
{
  List<T> listT = getT();
  List<V> listV = listT.ToList<V>()
}
```

Its says that `listT` dont contains a `ToList()` method.

The above implementation doesn't work.
But it works with concrete classes, like below:

```cs
interface Ifoo{}
class Bar : Ifoo{}

List<Bar> bar = getBar();
List<Ifoo> bar2 = bar.ToList<Ifoo>()
```

Why is that?
How can I make the method works with those generics constraint?

Comment: `Its says that listT dont contains a ToList() method` What **exactly** did it say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why `bar.ToList<Ifoo>()` works is because the *compiler* can be assured `Bar` implements `Ifoo`.

However, when you are in the generic context, even with the constraints that `T` is `V` the *compiler* cannot resolve the extension method (even though we assume it should be capable of it).

It's likely you just want to use [`Cast`](http://Enumerable.Cast%3CTResult%3E(IEnumerable)%20Method)... Assuming `T` can be *cast* to `V`:

> Casts the elements of an IEnumerable to the specified type

**Example**

```
List<V> listV = getT().Cast<V>().ToList();
```